# Equation in MATLAB and Python given different result

Tags: python, matlab

Currently I'm translating my MATLAB code to Python version,

```
function u = afterslip(A, B, C, D, E, X, Ta, Tb, Tc)
    u = A*log(1+X/Ta) + B + C*log(1+X/Tb) - D*exp(-X/Tc) + E;
end
```

to:

```
from math import log,exp

def afterslip(A, B, C, D, E, Ta, Tb, Tc):
    e = A*log(1+X/Ta) + B + C*log(1+X/Tb) - D*exp(-X/Tc) + 
    return e
```

But when I calculated using `X=187`, `Ta=8`, `Tb=80`, `Tc=600`, `A=-27`, `B=-18`, `C=56`, `D=-71`, and `E=-18` both given different result. Anyone knows why this happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Your missing the `E` in the end of the python function. Also when you say "different results" can you give the actual ones you got from each.

Answer (score 1):

The second function misses argument `X`. See below.

```
def afterslip(A, B, C, D, E, X, Ta, Tb, Tc):
    return A*log(1+X/Ta) + B + C*log(1+X/Tb) - D*exp(-X/Tc) + E
```

Comment: Please don't "fix" code in question edits, regardless what you think the asker's intentions are, it should be (and was already) addressed in comments, or resolved with an answer. The formatting improvements were OK.